# Getting only the count of odata expand property

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I have a OData service with WebAPI OData 6.0.0, and it supports queries like this:

```
/Customers?$expand=Projects($count=true)
```

This will return a list of Customers with all the Projects underneath each Customer with the count of those projects in addition for each.

What I now would like to have is a query that will get the list of customers, and for each customer ONLY the count of its projects, not the list of projects.

Is there a way to create such a query?

I tried

```
/Customers?$select=Name,Projects/$count
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can kind of accomplish this by using `$expand` with `$top` option. It will output **Projects** as an empty collection.

```
/Customers?$select=Name&$expand=Projects($count=true;$top=0)
```

Comment: Those reading this in 2022, there's a known issue using `$top=0`, which is fixed in EF6 https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2026